# How to receive parameters from MS-DOS and compares it in Assembly 16-bits?

Tags: assembly, command-line, x86, dos, tasm

Good night, what's the **simpliest** way to receive a **simple char** as parameter in ***Assembly 16-BITS***, and compares to test if is the right one? I'm for 2 days searching for examples of how to do it, but no one had worked for me... **I tried that** [code from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448788/how-to-pass-retrieve-dos-command-line-parameters-in-a-16-bit-assembly-program) and it doesn't work, the dx has 81h no the hex of the char that I need. I'm very newbie in Assembly, so **I need little examples of code to understand**... I want the **simpliest way possible, I don't want to waste your time**... Thanks. **In MS-DOS shell I'll call my program with a char in front**, like ***"MOVE A"***. The example in that code cited above works like an **Echo**, **but I can't compares the char inserted on command line.** I'm on **Windows 98 with TASM 4.1** I tried the example of the book **Art of Assembly** cited on the link, of **chapter 13.3.12**, the one talking about **PSP**, and, doesn't work for what I need. I think people are not understanding what I wanna learn. **Thanks guys**

Comment: We understand what you want, you don't understand us. You **do** need it from the PSP, offset 81h. That sample code loaded the address because you need that for that function. Otherwise you can just `mov al, [81h]` or `cmp [81h], 'a'` or similar. PS: use less bold font, thank you.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about! I tried it in a lot of ways, but doesn't work. Seems that char don't goes to register....

Comment: Yeah, of course. And I don't know how to debug and program that needs to parameters to work. I'm almost giving up of it...

Comment: Also doesn't work [photo](http://i.imgur.com/rsIP7i9.jpg)
In this Test the program only would print if A was send. But it doesn't

Comment: http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/debug.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the command line is at `81h` as you have already been told. In those examples however the address had to be passed to a print string function. If you want to access the character itself, you will need a memory load, not just its address. At least with the dosbox version I have available, the command name is not included, but the separating space is. So the actual argument character if you invoke your program as `move a` will be at offset `82h`. This sample code will thus load and print the letter:

```
org 100h

mov dl, ds:[82h]
mov ah, 06h
int 21h
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
```

Apparently `tasm` needs the `ds:` prefix otherwise it emits a `[Constant] assumed to mean immediate constant` warning and proceeds to use it as an immediate not an address.

PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I used `82h` and told you the reason for it.  So why do you have `81h`? Also you created an exe file, while you have been asking for a com file all along. This will only work as a com file.

Comment: Also doesn't works with [82h] [PRINTSCREEN](http://i.imgur.com/9azpvge.jpg) @Jester

Comment: Now you have `mov ah, 02h` instead of `mov ah, 06h` ... wrong function code.

Comment: That's the same screenshot and has **02** not **06**

Comment: Now you load `dl` but compare `al`. Works [here](http://imgur.com/fG73psP)

Comment: Can you send me your sourcecode please? What's your compiler? Here stil doesn't working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132244/discussion-between-user3587527-and-jester).